# TypeScript - is there an established way to throw error when given null/undefined?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing some code in TypeScript where I convert some untyped object (likely some kind of JSON) into a typed class by setting all the properties from the object into the class. I want to throw an error if that untyped object does not have the properties I am looking for in my class.

I was looking for a concise way to do this in TypeScript and came up with this. As far as I can tell it works, but to me it feels a little hacky. I was wondering if other developers know of an established way of doing this or whether this is fine as is.

```
const invalid = () => {throw new Error("Invalid input given in User.")}
this.firstName = obj.firstName ?? invalid();
this.lastName = obj.lastName ?? invalid();
this.email = obj.email ?? invalid();
```

Alternatively, if anyone knows of an easier way to convert an untyped object to a class, I'm all ears.

Comment: This looks like a special case of runtime type checking.  Have you looked into libraries like [io-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/) that will make type guards for you?  I mean, is `null`/`undefined` the only possible problem here?  What if your property should be a `string` but in the JSON it's a `number`?

Comment: Thank you for the library -- I'll look into it. I think the place I'm taking the JSONs from will be taken from somewhere where the names/emails should be strings, but you're right, it may make sense to simply throw an error in other cases too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most versatile way I have come across is to define a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).
For example (TypeScript Playground:

```
interface IUser {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
}

function isIUser(potentialIUser: any): potentialIUser is IUser {
    return "firstName" in potentialIUser && "firstName" in potentialIUser && "firstName" in potentialIUser;
}

class User implements IUser {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public email: string;

    constructor(user: IUser) {
        if(!isIUser(user)){
            throw new TypeError("Provided user is not compatible with interface IUser");
        }
        this.firstName = user.firstName;
        this.lastName = user.lastName;
        this.email = user.email;
    }
}

async function whoAmI(): Promise<User> {
    const user: IUser = await (await fetch("example.com/api/user/me")).json();
    return new User(user);
}
```

This gives you three advantages:

1. Conveniently, if you have unions like `AuthenticatedUser | GuestUser`, you already have a function to determine which it is.
2. Using `TypeError` gives JS the exact same error, with zero dependencies.
3. This also gives you functions to construct `Users` from other sources with minimal changes

Comment: Thank you for writing out the example code! I actually did see something similar to this in TypeScript's documentation but don't think that `"property" in object` function in TypeScript checks to see if the property is filled with nullish values -- just the existence of the property in the object. Fortunately an above comment mentions a library to do this sort of checking.